# wso2 carbon registry - high level use cases

Tags: wso2

The carbon registry seems to have multiple purposes in the WSO2 carbon platform.  It would be useful to understand the high level use cases that the registry is used for.  Here are some that I can think of:

- Storing internal WSO2 product configuration for clustering, etc
- Storing configuration data for shaing between custom applications or services
- As a content repository for WSO2 governance server, e.g. for wsdls, documents, etc

Are these use cases correct?
Are there any more use cases?

Is it appropriate to think of the carbon registry as providing similar functionality to windows registry but it is also accessible remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should be able to read up all the features and use cases here [1]. i hope this is what you are looking for check out the faqs here [2]. and take an look at the Enterprise Use Case Webinar here[3].

[1] http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/

[2] http://wso2.org/library/articles/faqs-governance-service

[3] http://wso2.org/library/webinars/2012/08/enterprise-use-case-webinar-application-governance-wso2-governance-registry

Edit:

Yes the use cases that you have mentioned are valid and cover most of the use cases of WSO2 Greg with other WSO2 products below some i think you missed but this may not be all the use cases

- Handling life cycles management
- Integrating with BAM to achieve monitoring related use cases [4]
- Integrating with API Manager to handle API's [5]
- Deployment synchroniser for dynamic configurations in clustering - will be available in future releases in addition to the exiting svn based model

[4] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Business+Activity+Monitor

[5] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/API+Manager

Comment: I was looking for use cases of the registry as installed with Carbon, not for use cases of the governance registry.

Comment: ahh ok i think i misunderstood your question then, will get back to you when i get an more clear answer to your query.

Comment: many thanks for the update.  So, would you say that in some ways the WSO2 registry is the equivalent of the windows registry in that it can be used for storing an applications configuration data?

Comment: i am not able to give an exact answer to that question the main aim for WSO2 Greg is to provide SOA Governance take a look at this think it might help http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Registry+Life-cycles+and+Forrester%27s+Major+SOA+Requirements